# Jquery document ready with function declaration?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know why the below code works differently when according to the documentation it should do the same thing.
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

First example:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        document.write("And what?");
    });
</script>
```

- It actually overwrites everything on the page and return only "And What?"....

Second example:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(test());

    function test() {
        document.write("And what?");
    }
</script>
```

- It actually returns the content of the page with "And what?" at the end of it, so it does append the text but why?!

What are the difference between those two functions and how to get the same example with Yahoo YUI?

Comment: The second one would have been equivalent if you had used `$(document).ready(test);` (without *calling* `test()`)

Answer (score 0):

`document ready` and `document write` are not the same thing:

`document.ready` is a **jQuery** event that will be triggered after your DOM finish to load. 
`document.write` is a native function of **JavaScript** that will override all the content of your page by the value you send as argument.

The difference between the 2 codes you show is that in the first one you are sending a function as param and in the second one you are sending the result of function as param because you are calling `test` when you include the **braces**.

So with your codes the problem is that in 1 you call the function after DOM is ready and in 2 you exec the function at the time you call it.

To have same result in both code you should to remove braces when you send test function as param in the second example:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(test);

    function test() {
        document.write("And what?");
    }
</script>
```

Besides this little different the 2 results that you are getting are because is the "strange" way that `document.write` works. Check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) which explains why this happens.

Comment: What the difference does it make what i send as a parameter since it should wait in both cases for doom to be loaded, so it should overwrite the page in both examples. How does that even append it using ready function is just a mystery to me...

Comment: @pit_ns No, because 1 is executed after DOM is loaded and 2 is executed before DOM is loaded. The second code is not sending a function as param is just executing it. Anyway the result you get is strange but is the way that document write works. Check out doc (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)

Comment: @pit_ns What you need to understand (besides the doc write behavior) is that you have a little but important difference in both codes.

Comment: Does that matter then if i wait for doom to be loaded in the second case? Would that make any difference if I just wrote: 
<script>
    function test() {
        document.write("And what?");
    }
 test();
</script>

Would that not work the same then as the second example?

Comment: @pit_ns Yes it matter, if you wait for DOM you will get same result as 1 if you do what you write beside you will get exactly the same result you are getting now at 2. This happens because using document.write to a document that has already loaded will automatically perform a document.open which clears the DOM. The documentation says how to handle this.

Comment: If so, what is the difference between?
function test() {
 document.write("And what?");
}
test();
AND
$( document ).ready(test());

function test() {
 document.write("And what?");
}
It seems both do exactly the same, when the second should wait for doom to be loaded but i guess it just doesn't..

Comment: @pit_ns Basically the difference is that the DOM has already loaded.

Comment: It has loaded with which example the second?

Comment: @pit_ns No, the first one is executed when DOM is ready, the second is execute at the moment you call it. This the difference in your code... the result you get is just the way document.write works.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `document.write()` after the document has finished loading, then the browser will clear your current page and start a new blank page.  That is how it is written to work.  So this:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        document.write("And what?");
    });
</script>
```

will always clear the page and start a new one with only `"And What?"` in it.

---

Your second code example would generate the same result if you didn't mistakenly call the test function before `$(document).ready()` fires.  If you did this:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(test);

    function test() {
        document.write("And what?");
    }
</script>
```

You would get the same result as above.

---

Instead, when you do this:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(test());

    function test() {
        document.write("And what?");
    }
</script>
```

You're calling `test()` immediately (it is not waiting for the doc to be ready) and then passing it's return value (which is `undefined`) to `$(document).ready()`.

To pass a function reference so it can be called LATER, you pass only the function's name without parens after it.  If you put parens after the name, you are instructing the JS interpret to execute the function right now and pass the return result instead.  If you pass only the function's name, you are passing a function reference that the function can then call later.